# Coded UI - How to write search and filter in Page object model

Tags: c#, automation, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, browser-automation

I am learning Coded UI test automation at the moment and developing a page object model for my POC. Could someone provide me some input/guidance on how to write a page object method for an object that requires search and filter together, Say to navigate to a BUTTONCLICK.

My webpage has several widgets in its dashboard and each has a settings menu. To locate the setting icon, the similar xpath would "//div[@id="HomeplayerWidget"]//button[@id='position-setting-button']

All settings icon share the same id and hence need to navigate through the corresponding widgetid. I am currently stuck at this and would appreciate any help on this.

//Updated with the HTML Code

Ignore the previous Xpath:
I tried using the Coded UI Record and search facility and it identified every data in the node except the "data-target" parameter in the below node. That is only thing that is unique with reference to each settings button in my Widgets page.

```
<button title="Settings" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" id="position-setting-button" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#position-setting-modal"></button>
```

Coded UI records the same set of Search/Filter properties for all the settings menu.

`this.mUIItemButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Id] = "position-setting-button";
this.mUIItemButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Name] = null;
this.mUIItemButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.DisplayText] = " "; this.mUIItemButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Type] = "button";
this.mUIItemButton.FilterProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Title] = "Settings";
this.mUIItemButton.FilterProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Class] = "btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right"; this.mUIItemButton.FilterProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "title=\"Settings\" class=\"btn btn-primary ";`

Either I need an option to identify a root element to locate the right button or need to know the option to use the data-target as a key to identify. Any inputs please?

Comment: Coded UI's basic search mechanism supports `SearchProperties` and `FilterProperties` on each control. The `SearchProperties` are used first then, if needed, the `FilterProperties` are used to narrow the results to one control.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I am aware of this properties theoritcally, but need it as an example of how to implement that in a hand coded model. When I looked into the UI Control Map, I saw the filter properties from the same tag, but in my case, I need to identify a root DIV element and then need to navigate the DIV element to find the appropriate node. I even tried to look into the UI Map, but i reckon it works with the combination of mouse location and property information and hence confusing.

Comment: You should let Coded UI guide you on how to hand code things. In a sandbox project use Coded UIs record and generate facilities, then copy useful code and ideas into your code.

Comment: Thanks again. Updated my questionw with Coded UI's RECORD and generate code. Please let me know if have any inputs?

Comment: You might experiment using a mix of `FindMatchingControls()` (and possibly `GetChildren()`) to visit all the relevant controls. For each control found write the values of all interesting fields to a text file to analyse after the run. I have learnt a lot about individual screens by variations on this technique